# Прокрутка Button WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть событие клик по кнопке:

```
void new_button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        btn.?
    }
```

Хочу, чтобы при клике кнопка поворачивалась на 90 градусов. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать с помощью триггеров:

```
 <Button Width="100" Height="50" Content="bla-bla">
     <Button.Style>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
              <Style.Triggers>
                   <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                       <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                           <Setter.Value>
                               <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                           </Setter.Value>
                       </Setter>
                   </Trigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
       </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

**UPD**
    Вынести стиль в ресурс окна:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

> Я хочу чтобы 1 нажатие - один поворот. и мне нужно, чтобы не все кнопки поворачивались. А определенные.

Укажите в стиле `x:Key="styleBtn"` и затем на кнопках которые хотите поворачивать укажите стиль:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource styleBtn}"/>
```

Comment: Не, у меня не фиксированное кол-во кнопок. Пользователь сам решает сколько их у него будет. Мне нужно универсальное решение на c#, потому что они генерируются по запросу пользователя :)

Comment: @Saint: Ну вынесите стиль в `ResourceDictionary`.

Comment: а нельзя написать что то вроде:
        btn.RotateTransformation = (0.5, 0.5);
не ругайтесь, взял всё из головы :)

Comment: @S.Kost а как его вынести, подскажите. пожалуйста?

Comment: @Saint: Можно, но не нужно. Это ж не WinForms, отвыкайте писать так.

Comment: @VladD А как теперь воспользоваться ресурсом в шарпе?

Comment: @Saint: А вы попробуйте как в коде после UPD. Этот стиль автоматически применится.

Comment: @VladD простите, не понял) Стиль применится, а как кнопку поворачивать при клике?))

Comment: @Saint: Ну, вы положите в окне вот такой стиль, как в ответе. (Эта часть понятна?) И потом добавьте в окно любое количество кнопок. Они все будут поворачиваться.

Comment: @VladD да, но только всё прыгает теперь. Я хочу чтобы 1 нажатие - один поворот. и мне нужно, чтобы не все кнопки поворачивались. А определенные.

Comment: @Saint обновил ответ

Comment: @S.Kost отлично, спасибо!
но только кнопки у меня не прописаны в XAML, они генерируются при указании пользователем их кол-ва. У меня кнопки доступны по buttons[i, j].Click . Как мне воспользоваться вашим предложением в этом случае?

Comment: @Saint , а зачем пользователю генерировать кнопки если не секрет? Что будут выполнять эти кнопки?

Comment: @S.Kost это игра "взлом сейфа".
На форме поворачиваемые рукоятки (кликом мышки меняется положение рукоятки с вертикального в горизонтальный и обратно).
Рукоятки расположены квадратом, как 2-мерный массив NxN.
Число N должно быть настраиваемое.
Я решил создать массив из поворачиваемых кнопок.

Comment: @Saint Можно вынести ресурсы в файл App.xaml, затем получить его вот так `Style style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["styleBtn"];`. Ну и потом присвоим к кнопкам этот стиль.

Comment: @S.Kost а как вынести ресурсы в файл App.xaml ?

Comment: @Saint откройте его и скопируйте туда стили